# Dimensions of train and test set are null in R

Tags: r, list, split, dimensions

I made a train and test set using my selfmade function:

```
splitter <- function(dataset, number1, number2 = 0.7){
  trn_index <- createDataPartition(y = dataset[,number1],
                                   p = number2, list = FALSE)
  trn_set = dataset[trn_index,]
  tst_set = dataset[-trn_index,]
  data <- list(trn_set = as.list(trn_set), 
               tst_set = as.list(tst_set))
}

general_splits <- splitter(general, 2, 0.6)

table(general_splits$trn_set$Attrition)
```

The purpose was to make a function that divides a dataset into a train and test set on the basis of three variables: the dataset, the column to make the split on (number1) and the fraction of rows in the train / test set (number2). It returns this as a list object. I want to split the general dataset.

When I try to check if it worked out, I see great results:

```
> table(general_splits$trn_set$Attrition)
   No    Yes 
   2185  419

> table(general_splits$tst_set$Attrition)
   No    Yes 
   1456  278
```

However, when I want to check the dimensions of the sets in my nested dataframe, the result is this:

```
> dim(general_splits$trn_set)
NULL
```

What am I missing here? The dataset has around 3500+ rows and 21 variables  and this is visible from the tables.

Comment: Just remove `as.list` and do `list(trn_set = trn_set, tst_set = tst_set)`. Also, the last instruction should be just the return value `data`. I'm voting to close as simple typo.

Comment: The structure of `general_splits` may not be what you expect. You should use [edit] facilities in SO to amend you question and include the output of `str(general_splits)`.